# using do while loop in fetching location from google api client

Tags: android

I am fetching the location from googleApiClient, when i click on yes in the alert builder of google, then i use onActvityResult to check that if user clicks yes then i set my text view to that location, i am not getting the last location at the same time, so i used do while loop,is it a good practice?
these are the functions to get the location and i set it to text view in onActivityResult method in my activity, please tell me, using this do while is a good practice??

```
public Location getCurrentLatLong() {
    checkLastLocation();
    Log.w("checkingsAct", mLastLocation + "");
    if(mLastLocation != null) {
        Log.w("checkingsAct", mLastLocation+"");
        latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        mLastLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        mLastLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
        Log.w("discheck", latitude + "" + " " + longitude);
    }
    return mLastLocation;

}
public void checkLastLocation() {
    do {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.w("checkingsAct", mLastLocation + "do called");
    } while(mLastLocation == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You  need to request for location update like below

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, locationListener);
```

If once locaiton is updated,  you will get call back in `void onLocationChanged(Location location)` method.

Comment: and then in this location changed method, can i  use set text in textview

Comment: Yes you can use this method to set the textView

Comment: but i used getting location method in another class, not in the activity

Comment: You need to implement some call back mechanism to give update to the activity or get the textView reference to you location class from constructor

Comment: where should i call this location services location updates method, because i am getting null pointer exception by calling this

Comment: Where exactly you are getting NPE?

Comment: i got it finally, now i am getting the location updates without any problem using this method you provided, thanks a lot for the help